# "npm not being able to find a file abbrev" when installing aurelia cli

Tags: linux, npm, aurelia

I am installing aurelia-cli in my production version. I am following instruction from  'http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli', now everytime when I am trying to run `npm install aurelia-cli -g` it gives me below error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-042stab113.11
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "aurelia-cli" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-d3948789
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-d3948789' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-d3948789' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /etc/apt/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: are you sure you are using an updated version of node and npm?

Comment: It seems like the problem is most likely related to node.js and npm, rather than with aurelia.

Comment: yes, I am using update version of both and  the problem is related to the npm only but how to resolve this error..

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about that specific error, however, this often works for me, and this method of doing a fresh reinstall is often recommended on gitter by the aurelia folks:

```
npm uninstall -g aurelia-cli
npm clear cache
npm install -g aurelia-cli
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
npm install # on freebsd sometimes I have to run this more than once
```